# R: Finding an object specifed by multi objects

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains gene_id, transcript_id and a dIF. I want to find all the gene_id's that has a transcription_id with a corresponding dIF-value of greater than 20 AND a transcript_id with a corresponding dIF-value of less than -20.

Example:

```
gene_id   transcript_id   dIF
A         B               3
A         C               32
A         D              -41
X         Y               2
X         Z              -13
```

I want find a way to get `A` returned (as it has `C > 20` and `D < -20`).
Should I try to write a `for` loop or is there a package that can help me?

Comment: An expected output would be helpful to better understand your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my `dplyr` solution. My approach is to `group_by` transcript_id and then filter rows based on multiple logical conditions. Is it want you want? Maybe I didn't get it.

```
df %>% group_by(transcript_id) %>% filter(dIF > 20 | dIF < -20)
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: transcript_id

  gene_id transcript_id dIF
1       A             C  32
2       A             D -41
```

#### Edit: comment of @thelatemail

Thank you for testing my code. The provided solution here can be a good one? let me now if my code still doesn't work well.

```
df %>% group_by(transcript_id) %>% filter(dIF > 20 | dIF < -20) %>% filter(gene_id == "A")
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: transcript_id

  gene_id transcript_id dIF
1       A             C  32
2       A             D -41
```

Comment: Ok, I had this first try but I feared I didn't get what you wanted.

Comment: Is it possible to get the dIF values in the output aswell?

Comment: Perfect! I have not used `dplyr` before, but after reading its help pgae, it looks like a very useful package!

Comment: The code doesn't work as intended. E.g. `df$dIF[5] <- -21; df %>% group_by(transcript_id) %>% filter(dIF > 20 | dIF < -20)` returns a row of `X` as well even though it only meets one of two criteria. Something like `df %>% group_by(gene_id) %>% filter(any(dIF > 20) & any(dIF < -20))` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you @thelatemail for your contribution and testing my code. I fear that code in your comment would select also `A` where `dIF` is 3. I had this output even though honestly speaking I can't realize yet why it happens.

Comment: @sabdem - You would need a more detailed piece of code I think - `df %>% group_by(gene_id) %>% filter(any(dIF > 20) & any(dIF < -20) & (dIF > 20 | dIF < -20) )`

Comment: Thank you, @thelatemail I have edited the question and your code produces the same output of mine (of course using `df$dIF[5] <- -21`).

Comment: @SabDeM - your code explicitly references filtering to `gene_id=="A"` - which is not flexible to different data sets. You should try to aim for generic code which works in all contexts.

Comment: @SabDeM - True, but notice that my code doesn't mention `A` at all, yet still returns it as required. You could recode `A` to `Z` and it would still work as intended.